# Problems prompting for input from an SSIS package

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, input, ssis

I am very new to C# and its use in SSIS.  I found a great suggestion in the question presented back in 2011 ([How do I prompt for input from an SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107289/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-from-an-ssis-package)) offered by https://stackoverflow.com/users/85952/sreedhar.  I made some slight changes to the C# code in the script task.  I don't get any errors, but I have 2 issues that I need to resolve:

1.)  The changes I made to prompt for 2 different pieces of data cause the second prompt to display the results of the first prompt.

2.)  The variables seem to populate within the script but come across empty after it runs.

Please forgive my ignorance, but I am in strange waters here.  I have included my amended code below.

Thanks,

Rich

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = new Form();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    Button inputset = new Button();
    String VartoSet;

    public void Main()
    {
        inputset.Text = "Enter Year to Query On";
        inputset.Width = 200;
        inputset.Height = 100;
        VartoSet = "User::QYear";
        inputset.Click += new EventHandler(inputset_Click);
        txt.Name = "Input";
        frm.Controls.Add(txt);
        frm.Controls.Add(inputset);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables[VartoSet].Value.ToString());

        inputset.Text = "Enter Period to Query On";
        VartoSet = "User::QMonth";
        inputset.Click += new EventHandler(inputset_Click);
        txt.Name = "Input";
        frm.Controls.Add(txt);
        frm.Controls.Add(inputset);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables[VartoSet].Value.ToString());

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    void inputset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dts.Variables[VartoSet].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);
        frm.Close();
    }
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mee by "The variables seem to populate within the script but come across empty after it runs". What is coming across empty?

Answer (score 0):

I am not C# expert l have had a look at the code and this works for me.

```
   System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = new Form();
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    Button inputset = new Button();
    String VartoSet;

    public void Main()
    {
        inputset.Text = "Enter Period to Query On";
        inputset.Width = 200;
        inputset.Height = 100;
        //VartoSet = "User::QMonth";
        inputset.Click += new EventHandler(inputset_Click);
        txt.Name = "Input";
        frm.Controls.Add(txt);
        frm.Controls.Add(inputset);
        frm.ShowDialog();
        MessageBox.Show( Dts.Variables["User::QMonth"].Value.ToString());

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    void inputset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::QMonth"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);
        frm.Close();
    }
```

From what l can see the argument for assigning a value to a variable has to be a string literal, not a string variable.  This is the way l have always done it and l could not find any examples of using a string variable for the variable name.  Despite that fact that l agree it should work that way!

Or in other words

This works -> Dts.Variables["User::QMonth"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);

This is did not -> Dts.Variables[VartoSet].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txt.Text);

The next step is to get it to work for both variables.