# Transfer SQL Objects using ssis according to given name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Suppose, We have two databases , db_1 and db_2.

There are a table named 'T1' in db_1, now,I need a package in SSIS which will ask for names sql objects.If I choose 'T1',the data will be transfered to db_2.

I dont know if it is possible.

Comment: Your subject and requirement seems different. you want to transfer Object (table/View/Fn) or data?

Answer (score 0):

Generally SSIS is not meant to be used in an Interactive mode. Any user input is either introduced as a config setting or environment variable or as values in some other table.

Alternately, you can also prompt for and capture input values outside of the SSIS Package and then execute the SSIS Package, in C# or ASP.Net or any other interactive platform.

That said, ***if you must prompt for input and use it***, the way to do it is by instantiating and displaying a Form in a **Script Component**.

Create a variable at the appropriate scope called `tableName` in the package. Then use the code below (modify it as needed) to set the `tableName` variable's value to whatever the user enters. Finally, use the same `tableName` variable in your control flow to copy the data from.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form frm = new Form();
TextBox      = new TextBox();
Button submitButton = new Button();

public void Main()
{
    submitButton.Text = "Enter source table name";
    submitButton.Width = 300;
    submitButton.Height = 80;
    submitButton.Click += new EventHandler(submitButton_Click);
    tableNameTextBox.Name = "Input";
    frm.Controls.Add(tableNameTextBox);
    frm.Controls.Add(submitButton);
    frm.ShowDialog();
    MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["tableName"].Value.ToString());


    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}

void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dts.Variables["tableName"].Value = tableNameTextBox.Text;
    frm.Close();
}
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4121557/325521