# Visual Studio 2019 SSIS-Extension log4j files

Tags: ssis, log4j, visual-studio-2019

Due to the recent problems with log4j I was checking all my code etc..
While doing so i discovered two files named

"slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar" and "log4j-1.2.17.jar"

to find under

"...\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Extensions\Common\Jars"

Since we are also developing SSIS packages we kinda rely on this extension.
Sadly I was not able to find anything about SSIS in context with log4j. IMO it's also a bit dubious that the version of the log4j seems to be 1.x, which support ended in 2015.

Are there any known fixes/updates?

Comment: I agree with Francesco's reasoning of unlikely vector of attack, the jars appear to be related to the hadoop components. For a 140 install, the logging is referenced as `commons-logging-1.1.3.jar`

Comment: Now this makes more sense @billinkc , we are now restricting the range of the vulnerability only to Hadoop components. So not every package could be exploited. 
...but maybe SSIS packages related to Hadoop can be exploited. I will try myself if I can build up a lab

Comment: @billinkc, I missed how can you tell that this is related to Hadoop only. Can you clarify, please? Thank you

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCdX6.png My logic/justification is based on the other .jars in the folder and trying to fathom what tasks/components they'd be used in

Comment: it looks like the affected version is only the Log4j 2 and the older ones are not affected by this vulnerability https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/662469/log4j-vulnerability-concerns.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem.

In what way those .jar file can be exploited to trig a privilege escalation or software evasion?

The fact that Visual Studio is using old libraries doesn't shock me at all. Large companies are use to rely on third party library and then they are usually forbidden in the corner during years.

**EDIT:**

You question was somehow interesting and I needed to dig further.

Apparently this 0-day [has been around since March](https://github.com/nice0e3/log4j_POC?s=09), so it means 9 month ago. There is no [evidence of mass exploitation](https://twitter.com/eastdakota/status/1469800951351427073) but that doesn't mean that it hasn't been used in the past months.

In order to [use it](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2021/12/on-the-log4j-vulnerability.html):

> [...] an attacker only needs to get the system to log a strategically
> crafted string of code. From there they can load arbitrary code on the
> targeted server and install malware or launch other attacks. Notably,
> hackers can introduce the snippet in seemingly benign ways, like by
> sending the string in an email or setting it as an account username.

This means that **hypothetically** you can exploit the vulnerability through SSIS in this scenario:

1. Create an SSIS package that ask for an [input to the client user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107289/how-do-i-prompt-for-input-from-an-ssis-package)
2. The package must use log4j for logging
3. The user enter the malicious crafted [string of code](https://twitter.com/Laughing_Mantis/status/1470412026119798786)

...then yes in this case an SSIS package could be exploited.

I will try it out in my spare time and I will let you know.

**EDIT 2:**

After extensive research I can confirm you that this is not a problem because [only version Log4j 2.X are impacted](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html):

> Mitigation
>
> Log4j 1.x mitigation: Log4j 1.x is not impacted by this vulnerability.
>
> Log4j 2.x mitigation: Implement one of the mitigation techniques
> below.

Use [log4j-finder](https://github.com/fox-it/log4j-finder) developed by [FOX IT](https://www.fox-it.com/nl-en/) to enumerate vulnerable log4j files on your machines.

Answer (score 2):

**Microsoft have now removed the dependency**

There is a new version (3.16) of the SSIS tools for VS2019 which removes the dependency for log4j.

Here's the download link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

[Version 3.16 Upgrade Notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDf9v.png)